# fullcalendar - events offset by 2 days

Tags: fullcalendar

I am experiencing a very odd problem and I cannot reproduce it!

I have around 70 users using my app which has the calendar display events.
The events are loaded into the calendar from a PHP function which populates the eventsource.

On 68 of the users everything displays perfectly.
On 2 users, the events are displayed 2 days ahead of the actual event in the calendar.
i.e. Easter monday is an event that I am displaying and it displays in their calendar on the 23rd April instead of the 21st.

I have tried to reproduce this on my PC but am unable.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Col

Comment: Could you share some of your code with us?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 400, theme: true, firstDay: 1, header: { left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title', right: 'month, basicWeek ' },
    editable: true,
    events: [<?php echo $events; ?>]
    });    
    });
       
 
I populate the $events PHP variable from my database

Comment: Sorry, pasting code seems to be an issue on this browser for me. It must be Friday :)

Comment: JSFiddled it - http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3vw/

Comment: You might want to check the time zone on those users computers. Can you add the event data to the fiddle used for Easter Monday?

Comment: Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3vw/1/

Comment: Checked the timezones on user PC's, they are all GMT 0, same as the users that are not having the problem.

Comment: Is it a browser issue, have you checked the console for errors?